# Where to get the exclusion items in Spring Boot Starter Packages

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I'm using Spring initializr to have the necessary package and downloading. Once I download, there are changes that I'm making in the pom.xml like excluding packages like slf4j, logging (when i plan to use log4j2) and excluding tomcat when trying to deploy into standalone server.

I don't know what are the other items that are capable to exclude. Is there any documentation like which package contains additional artifacts? Trying to avoid certain jars while packaging so that I think I can reduce the package(jar/war) size.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

All spring boot starter packages can be found here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters

They are all just pom.xml files. You can exclude anything you want from any dependency you are using by analyzing the pom's dependencies in the started packages.